# if empty between tag <ul> give alert.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want if empty between tag `ul` alert `hello`. how is it?

```
<button class="click">Click</button><p>

<span>
    <ul></ul>
</span>
```

js:

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    if('span ul' == ''){alert('hello')};
});
```

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/KDAwP/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using jQuery `:empty` selector which selects empty elements. An empty element is an element without child elements or text.

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    if($('ul:empty').length){alert('hello')};
});
```

jQuery is not finding `ul` inside a `span` tag. Actually you should not have `ul` inside a `span` tag.

Try this fiddle it works perfectly fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/KDAwP/6/

Comment: @genesis - Yes, `$("span ul")` is not giving anything. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/KDAwP/6/

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the [`:empty` selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/). =)

Comment: Only issue here is :empty is slower than doing `'ul li'`

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $('div ul').each(function(){
        if(this.innerHTML == ''){ 
            alert('hello');
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

You **cannot** have a `ul` inside of a `span`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nxk7a/

Answer (score 0):

Tests on the solutions here: [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/testing-for-empty-ul)

Another solution which is faster than `:empty` is:

```
var isEmpty = jQuery("#foo ul li").length === 0;
```

But the interesting thing is if you have an id on the ul in question, using the html() is fastest.

```
var isEmpty = jQuery("#UL_ID").html().length === 0;
```

So the quickest way really depends on what the selector is.