# Get alert if all they(ul) are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can done if all tags ul in `.empty` is empty alert ok?(with jQuery)

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/pqgGr/

```
<div class="empty">
    <ul>1</ul>
    <ul></ul>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
if ($('.empty ul').is(":empty")) {
    alert('ok')
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263567/if-empty-between-tag-ul-give-alert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `:not()` to exclude the empty items, and see if that returns an empty collection:

```
if($('.empty ul:not(:empty)').length == 0) {
   alert('ok');
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tkcPZ/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var empty = true;

$('.empty ul').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).is(":empty"))
    {
         empty = false;
    }   
});

alert(empty);
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pqgGr/1/

Answer (score 1):

The `text` method will return the concatenation of the text content of each of the matched elements:

```
if($(".empty ul").text() === "") {
    alert("Empty!");
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/5E9b8/1/). However, note that this will only work if you only care about text. If there are child elements of the `ul` elements, and they don't have any text nodes within them, the `ul` will be seen as empty.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if($(".empty").attr('ul').is(':empty')){
    alert('ok')
}
```

You might also consider to trim white spaces before check

```
if($.trim($(".empty").attr('ul').is(':empty')))
{
    alert('ok')
}
```